# Python - Quadratic Equatin Extreme numbers

Tags: python, numeric, numerical-methods, equation, quadratic

I have written code to solve quadratic equation in Python. But it has errors with very large numbers like "1e10" and "-1e10". Is there any solution numerically or as python solution?

```
enter code here
import math
import cmath

def solve_quad(b, c):

    a = 1
    D = b*b - 4*a*c

    if (D > 0):
        x1 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2*a)
        x2 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2*a)
    elif D == 0:
        x1 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2*a)
        x2 = x1
    else:
        x1 = (-b - cmath.sqrt(D)) / (2*a)
        x2 = (-b + cmath.sqrt(D)) / (2*a)


    return x1, x2
print(solve_quad(1e10, 4))
```

Output:
(-10000000000.0, 0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very old and often repeated topic. Let's explain it one more time. You use the binomial theorem to avoid numerical instability.

As the first root you chose the one where the sign of `-b` and the sign before the square root are the same.

```
if D>0:
    SD = D**0.5;
    if b > 0: SD = -SD
    x1 = (-b+SD) / (2*a)
```

Then for the second root you use the formula

```
(-b-SD) / (2*a) 
= (b^2-SD^2) / (2*a*(-b+SD)) 
= 4*a*c / (2*a*(-b+SD)) 
= (2*c) / (-b+SD)
```

to get

```
x2 = (2*c) / (-b+SD)
```

In the other cases the catastrophic cancellation that is avoided with this procedure does not occur.

This avoids completely all numerical instability due to catastrophic cancellation. If you want go further you can also try to avoid the potential overflow in the computation of the discriminant.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have issues with floating point precision. You could use Decimal or other similar library to get better precision and circumvent this:

```
from decimal import *

def solve_quad(b, c):
    a = 1
    D = b*b - 4*a*c

    if (D > 0):
        x1 = (-b - D.sqrt()) / (2*a)
        x2 = (-b + D.sqrt()) / (2*a)
    elif D == 0:
        x1 = (-b - D.sqrt()) / (2*a)
        x2 = x1
    else:
        x1 = (-b - D.sqrt()) / (2*a)
        x2 = (-b + D.sqrt()) / (2*a)

    return x1, x2

print(solve_quad(Decimal(1e10), Decimal(4)))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it doesn't work as python doesn't support arithmatic operations between complex and integer numbers.